# QuickSort too slow and ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsError

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, quicksort

I'm supposed to implement QuickSort for an assignment and I have a couple of problems. My code runs much slower than it's supposed to and I can't find what's slowing it down, since I followed our teachers pseudo code strictly.

Also when we submit this code it's tested, but we can't see the tests and it says I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error, which to me doesn't make sense as I already check if the limits are in the correct range.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
public QuickSort() {
     rand = new Random();
}

@Override
public void sort(int[] v) {
    sort(v, 0, v.length-1);     
}

/**
 * Sort an array from two set points, 
 * usually from first index to last.
 */
private void sort(int[] v, int first, int last){
    if(first >= last || last <= first || first < 0 || last < 0)
        return;
    else if(first >= last-10){
        Insertionsort.sort(v, first, last);
        return;
    }           
    else if(first < last && first >= 0){
        int rnd = first+rand.nextInt(last-first+1);
        swap(v, rnd, last);
        int mid = partition(v, first, last);
        sort(v, first, mid-1);
        sort(v, mid+1, last);
    }
}

/**
 * Swaps elements in array around a
 * pivot element.
 * < pivot to the left
 * > pivot to the right 
 */
private int partition(int[] v, int first, int last){        
    int x = v[last];
    int i = first-1;

    for(int j = first; j<last; j++){
        if(v[j] <= x){
            i++;
            swap(v, i, j);
        }
    }

    swap(v, (i+1), (last));

    return (i+1);
}

/**
 * Swap two elements in a list
 */
private void swap(int[] v, int a , int b){
    int temp = v[a];
    v[a] = v[b];
    v[b] = temp;
}
```

My InsertionSort class:

```
public class Insertionsort {

    public Insertionsort() {}

    public static void sort(int[] v, int first, int last){
        int j, toInsert;
        for (int i = first+1; i < v[last]; i++) {
            toInsert = v[i];
            j = i;
            while (j > 0 && v[j - 1] > toInsert) {
                v[j] = v[j - 1];
                j--;
            }
            v[j] = toInsert;
        }
    }
}
```

My superclass (we're supposed to implement this as we create different versions of QuickSort)

```
public interface IntSorter {

    /**
     * Sorts the array into ascending numerical order.
     */
    void sort(int[] v);
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it yourself? What are your test cases so far?

Comment: How do you call the `sort` method, where is your input?

Comment: What are your test cases? Can you post the **full exception stack trace**.

Comment: I tried to run it, but a) missing the super class/interface that declares sort(int[]), and b) missing Insertionsort.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom I have a main class where I have tested a couple of different arrays. Empty arrays, arrays with length 0, and arrays that have 1 million ints ranging from 0 to 99999.

Comment: @stjepano In my main class I call the sort method like this:
new QuickSort().sort(a); where a is the array. I also have a Stopwatch class that measures the time it takes to sort it.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom Thank you for taking your time and testing it. I added the interface and insertionsort class in the question.

Comment: I've tested {}, {0}, {1, 2} and {2, 1}. The first three pass. {2, 1} fails. No exception, though.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom You're right, it fails. I had only checked for exceptions before, so I missed that. I don't see how I could get an exception though, but maybe by solving the problem with {2, 1} will solve that too.
Any hint/idea what causes it?

Comment: Well, it falls into the Insertionsort logic, right? Debug into that, see what you see.

Comment: Ah. In Insertionsort, the `for` loop: `i < v[last]` s/b `i < last`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your QuickSort code, it's your Insertionsort.

In the `for` loop you calculate the loop termination incorrectly.

```
for (int i = first+1; i < v[last]; i++) {
```

In the case of {2, 1}, I found that the loop terminated prematurely. But imagine if `v[last]` was greater than the number of elements in `v`. That's right, `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`.

The moral of the story: testing with millions of randomly generated `ints` is a good idea, but testing with the little cases can also expose problems.

As for execution time, try adding the `static` keyword to `Insertionsort` like this:

```
public static void sort(int[] v, int first, int last){
```

and invoke it like this:

```
Insertionsort.sort(v, first, last);
```

That will eliminate the need to create an instance of `Insertionsort` just to sort a small section of the array. `Insertionsort` just does stuff for you without trying to remember anything (i.e. it is stateless), so a static method can be used.

Here's the jUnit test class that I used:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestQuicksort {
  @Test
  public void emptyArray() {
    QuickSort q = new QuickSort();
    int[] a = {};
    q.sort(a);
    assertEquals(0, a.length);
  }

  @Test
  public void oneElement() {
    QuickSort q = new QuickSort();
    int[] a = {0};
    q.sort(a);
    assertEquals(1, a.length);
    assertEquals(0, a[0]);
  }

  @Test
  public void oneTwo() {
    QuickSort q = new QuickSort();
    int[] a = {1, 2};
    q.sort(a);
    assertEquals(2, a.length);
    assertEquals(1, a[0]);
    assertEquals(2, a[1]);
  }

  @Test
  public void twoOne() {
    QuickSort q = new QuickSort();
    int[] a = {2, 1};
    q.sort(a);
    assertEquals("Array is " + Arrays.toString(a), 1, a[0]);
    assertEquals(2, a[1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: i < last didn't solve it, but i <= last did. I'm sure that's what you meant, so thank you very much. I wouldn't have solved it without your help. My program is however still slow, while others run all the tests on ~0.9 seconds my program runs it on 5.38 and the max was 6s. But anyway, thank you.

Comment: So, next step: profile it against a large data set. Figure out where (i.e. in which class/method) you're spending most of that time. Personally, I wonder how many instances of `Insertionsort` you end up creating. Think about that. Do you know about `static` methods?

Comment: In my other classes (that are slower and don't use insertionsort) I have the same problem with the time, so like you mentioned it probably is related to the number of instaces of Insertsort. I just don't really know how to measure the time, since the methods are recursive. And since I have to ask "what do you mean" I guess I don't know about static methods more than that methods have to be static if they're used in the main class.. :/

Comment: I made changes in the code in the question. Is that this new code what you meant? This static add to insertionsort class and the change in QuickSort to Insertionsort.sort(...)  made it slightly faster (5.09s prev: 5.38s) but maybe the main issue lies partition? Looping through 1 million elements in 1 for loop is not exactly very fast. Maybe if another loop was used so that two loops could work simultaneously, or something.

Comment: That's what I meant. `partition()` looks good. I'll keep looking.

Comment: I just tried with 1 million elements randomly generated between 0 and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Runs consistently in under 200 ms, and that's to generate the initial array, sort it, and verify that it's sorted at the end. I'm starting to wonder about your `StopWatch` class.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed rather quick. We're however supposed to post our solutions to Kattis, where the tests are run. I can't access nor see the tests, all I can see is the time it takes for my program to pass all tests and my coursemates'. It is here my runs over 5 times slower than my coursemates'. I will have to measure each method.

Comment: The `static` `InsertionSort` is surely a red herring - creation of a class is very cheap on a modern JVM; and there are unlikely to be that many created in any case. However, you get a +1 for laying out good, simple, unit tests that the OP can use. This is invaluable advice.